How can I cover fountain pen ink for wall paint?
Some time ago, I spilled some fountain pen ink, and it got all over my wall. I wasn't too upset because I was planning to repaint the room anyway, and I figured the paint would cover the stain.
It seems I was wrong. Try as I might, no matter how many coats of paint I apply, the ink shines through. I'm mystified. If it makes a difference, the ink is a Diamine Majestic Blue, the wall is a light color, and the paint is a similarly light-colored Benjamin Moore water-based latex paint.
What do I do? I even tried sanding off the ink but it seems it just seeped its way into the existing paint (which I presume was also a latex paint)

If the sealant doesn't work: Maybe try the opposite of covering: removing it entirely. If the colour didn't seep too deeply into the wall a belt sander could work wonders.

Is that you, Martin?

You need to seal the wall with a primer sealer.
This will seal the ink and prevent it from bleeding through the new paint.
Depending on the severity of the stain you may need to do an additional coat of sealer before the color coat of paint.
You can try to seal just the stained parts, but for best results the whole wall should be sealed and painted. This will prevent uneven or blotchy color.

I keep seeing advice that you should only apply latex primer to latex paint. Should I use a latex primer sealer or oil based?

Get some spray shellac primer and just spray those areas, it will block it back.

The link in my answer is for a water based sealer primer that is formulated to seal Ink, among other things.

A previous house had one wall which the previous owner had painted kiddie animals on.  These kiddie animals included 'artistic eyes' which came through no matter how much sealer or paint was applied.  It took a coat of drywall mud to cover them.  Of course, once you apply drywall mud, it will be necessary to apply a sealer coat prior to the final paint layer.

you can try different types of sealer, if a water based sealer doesn't work try an alcohol based sealer (eg B.I.N) or a solvent based sealer.  you need for the base of the sealer not to dissolve the stain.

I can only imagine the fun of repainting the wall, and then the eyes slowly appearing over the following days to make sure the house can watch you.

@Sean Duggan - that was the problem.  No matter how much sealer/paint applied those eyes were still watching.  I forget if it was one or two coats of drywall mud before those ghosts disappeared.

Depends how big the area is, but here's what I'd do;

Sand area down until ink splodges removed along with surrounding paint. Start with 80 grit, finish with 120
Clean & dry area then mist coat (paint sanded area with diluted mix of paint, e.g. 30% water)
Once dry, apply 2x top coats, ideally to whole wall

Done.
Don't see the need to complicate things by burying problem with primers / drywall mud when you could just remove the problem marks and then paint over.
Unless of course after sanding you find the ink penetrated deep into plaster, in which case apply primer.
